# How to always scrape the first Link that pops up (no image links)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

```
for i in range(1,len(companynameslist)):
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i+1])
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.minimize_window()
googlebutton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
googlebutton.click()
linkedinsearch = 'site:www.linkedin.com “{}”'.format(companynameslist2[i])
search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
search.click()
search.send_keys(linkedinsearch)
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
currenturl = driver.current_url
source2 = requests.get(currenturl).text
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(source2, 'lxml')
links = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/a').click()
print(driver.current_url)
```

Hey guys, this program should scrape the LinkedIn company page of a google search input. i thought this would be the best way to do it (without having to log into LinkedIn), but the problem is that the XPath i used is sometimes invalid, if the google search shows images before the links. I can I skip these images and only scrape the company page?

Any help much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to improve your locators. Absolute XPaths are extremely breakable.
I tested the following code on several company names and it worked correct.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://google.com"
driver.get(url)


wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='q']"))).send_keys("Microsoft" + Keys.ENTER)
link = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search a[href]"))).get_attribute("href")
print(link)
```

The output is

```
https://www.microsoft.com/
```

So, actually all your code is changed here to 2 lines.
Again, I tested it on several company names. In case there will be exclusions - please let me know and I'll try to check more general solution if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much! it still prints out the pictures link, but i only need 65% accuracy so it works well, thanks!!

Comment: :) One quick question, is there a way to take the second link and not the first?